# Does centripetal force use radial velocity or tangential velocity

Tags: centripetal-force

The formula for centripetal force in rotational motion is $F = mv^{2}/r$,
where $r$ is the radius.

And now we take the force to be Coulombic. The direction of force is inwards (force between two opposite charges where the charge in the centre is nucleus (positive), and the other is the electron in the orbit (negative)).
Now, if we take a look at the right-hand side of the equation, we have used velocity. The direction of the radius $r$ is always outwards. But what about the velocity? Is it *tangential* velocity or *radial* velocity.

Also, is it necessary for both the left- and right-hand terms to be exactly opposite in direction, i.e. the radial force outwards and the central force inwards, for the equation to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

For the motion of a point, we can write its velocity $\mathbf{v}$, as the product of the magnitude of the velocity $v$ and the unit vector tangent to the trajectory $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$,

$\mathbf{v} = v \mathbf{\hat{v}}$.

The acceleration is the time derivative of the velocity, that we can write as

$\mathbf{a} = \dfrac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt} (  v \mathbf{\hat{v}} )  = \dfrac{d v}{dt} \mathbf{\hat{v}} + v \dfrac{d \mathbf{\hat{v}} }{dt}$,

i.e. the acceleration can be written as the sum of two contributions, the first tangent to the trajectory of the point (the tangential acceleration), the latter perpendicular (take the derivative of $|\mathbf{\hat{v}}|^2 = \mathbf{\hat{v}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{v}} = 1$ to realize that $\mathbf{\hat{v}} \cdot \frac{d\mathbf{\hat{v}}}{dt} = 0$) to the trajectory (the centripetal acceleration).

The time derivative of the unit normal vector can be written as

$\dfrac{d \mathbf{\hat{v}} }{dt} = k v \mathbf{\hat{n}}$,

being $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ the unit normal vector pointing towards the center of the circle of curvature of the trajectory, $k$ the curvature of the trajectory defined as the inverse of the radius of curvature $k = \frac{1}{R}$.

Putting everything together

$\mathbf{a} =  \dfrac{d v}{dt} \mathbf{\hat{v}} + k v^2 \mathbf{\hat{n}}$.

Now, you can see the contributions of the acceleration in terms of tangent and normal unit vectors of the trajectory, its curvature, the magnitude of the velocity and the time derivative of the magnitude.

### Example: uniform circular motion

In a uniform circular motion, the magnitude $v$ of the velocity doesn't change, so $\frac{d v}{dt} = 0$, the radius of curvature is the radius of the circle, and the normal vector pointing towards the center of the circle is the unit vector $-\mathbf{\hat{r}}$, having introduced a system of polar coordinates with origin in the center of the circle. Thus you can write the acceleration as

$\mathbf{a} = - \dfrac{v^2}{R} \mathbf{\hat{r}}$.

Answer (score 0):

the inertial components of the centripetal force are
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{F}=-m\,\mathbf{\omega}\times\,\left(\mathbf{\omega}\,\times\mathbf R\,\right)
\end{align*}

for a circular motion you obtain

\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{F}=-m\,\begin{bmatrix}
              0 \\
              0 \\
              \omega_z \\
            \end{bmatrix}
\times \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
              0 \\
              0 \\
              \omega_z \\
            \end{bmatrix}\times 
\,\begin{bmatrix}
              x \\
              y \\
              0 \\
            \end{bmatrix}\,\right)  =
m\,\omega_z^2\,\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
with polar coordinates
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf{R}=r\,\begin{bmatrix}
               \sin(\theta) \\
               \cos(\theta) \\
               0 \\
             \end{bmatrix}~,
 \mathbf{e}_R=\begin{bmatrix}
                 \sin(\theta) \\
                 \cos(\theta) \\
                 0 \\
               \end{bmatrix}~,
 \mathbf{e}_\theta=\begin{bmatrix}
                 \cos(\theta) \\
                 -\sin(\theta) \\
                 0 \\
               \end{bmatrix}\\                
&\mathbf{F}=m\,\omega_z^2\,
r\,\begin{bmatrix}
               \sin(\theta) \\
               \cos(\theta) \\
               0 \\
             \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
thus $~m\,\omega_z^2\,r~$
is the components of the centripetal force towards
$~\mathbf{e}_R~$

with
\begin{align*}
& \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{\omega}\times \mathbf{R}=
 r\,\omega_z\,\begin{bmatrix}
   -\cos(\theta) \\
   \sin(\theta) \\
   0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}~,
 \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{e}_\theta=-\,r\omega_z\quad\Rightarrow\\
 &\mathbf{F}=m\,\omega_z^2\,\mathbf e_R=m\,\frac{|(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{e}_\theta)^2|}{r}\mathbf{e}_R=
 m\frac{v^2}{r}\mathbf{e}_R
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

centripetal force is the result of change in tangential momentum vector

Comment: Also if the momentum changing in the radial direction is not zero, you should add this changing into the centripetal force

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates let the unit vectors be $\hat n$ and $\hat l$ in the increasing radial, $r$, and angular, $\theta$, directions, respectively. The acceleration vector is $(\ddot r - r \dot {\theta ^2}) \hat n\, + \, (r\ddot \theta + 2\dot r\dot \theta) \hat l$.  The $- r \dot {\theta ^2}$ term is the centripetal acceleration arising from motion in the $\theta$ direction from $\dot \theta$, the change in time of $\theta$, and it is directed radially inward.  Any force that causes centripetal acceleration is called a centripetal force, such as the tension in a string for a particle moving with constant velocity in a circle.  The centripetal force acts in the radially inward direction.

Therefore, the Merriam Webster dictionary defines a centripetal force as "*the force that is necessary to keep an object moving in a curved path and that is directed inward toward the center of rotation*".